# ¿Cómo resolver este problema con privilegios para 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' en procedimientos?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy generando un proceso, el cual crea una vista con el comando de EXECUTE IMMEDIATE pero me dice que no tengo privilegios, le comenté a mi profesor y insiste en que no son permiso, por ejemplo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREAR_VISTA (ID_DATA IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1)
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace view VISTA_BITACORA as select * from bitacora where ID_DATA ='||ID_DATA;
END;
```

y al ejecutarlo lo ejecuto asi:

```
call CREAR_VISTA();
```

pero me da este error: SQL Error [1031] [42000]: ORA-01031: privilegios insuficientes

mas sin embargo si lo ejecuto asi :

```
DECLARE
  ID_DATA NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace view VISTA_BITACORA as select * from bitacora where ID_DATA ='||ID_DATA;
END;
```

Funciona perfectamente.

AGRADEZCO TODA AYUDA POSIBLE <3

Answer (score 0):

Profesor malo, malo *le pega con un periódico *

Los privilegios que se asignan vía ROLE no aplican dentro de un bloque PLSQL, sólo los que se otorgan directamente al esquema que corre el bloque.

Es decir, si el usuario `JULIAN` tiene asociado el rol `DBA`, tiene muchos permisos asociados. Pero dentro del bloque PLSQL (como el de un procedimiento), sólo son válidos los permisos asignados al usuario `JULIAN` directamente. Entonces, si `JULIAN` no tiene permiso para CREATE ANY TABLE`, falla la cosa al llamar el procedimiento :)